# If I have to reformat a disk where I'm storing a wallet, if the OS is Ubuntu, which files should be be saved prior to the reformat?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, wallet-recovery

I have a wallet on an Ubuntu installation, and I need to wipe the disk.  I have sent transactions from the wallet, so I want to preserve that history.  In any wallet `show_transfers` will provide the wallet ins and outs. I want to see the to: address and any other information that would be lost forever if I deleted the wallet.  Which files should I save?  Where are they located?  And do I need to perform specific CLI commands, or can I simply drag and drop them into an email to myself or a onto a USB stick for later?

Are the files in a similar location on Windows or Mac OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each wallet will have 3 files, see [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/what-data-do-the-wallet-files-contain) for more details.

The files are:

- `wallet-name` - wallet cache, note that there's no extension
- `wallet-name.keys` - the most important one (your keys)
- `wallet-name.address.txt` - only the plaintext address inside, not really needed

If you've used defaults, they should be all in the same folder as your Monero executables. All you have to do is copy these files, and that's it. When re-installing, you copy them back or use the

`--wallet-file <path>\wallet-name`

argument to tell the wallet where to look for the files and access them from there.

Answer (score 2):

For the standard command line wallet on Ubuntu the files should be stored in your user's home directory as 3 separate files called , .address.txt and .keys

The blockchain data is also stored in a folder called .bitmonero/lmdb, which is again in the user's home directory, if you want to save some time syncing later.

It has been a little while since I did this transfer myself, so I would recommend testing this method before nuking the drive, but as far as I'm aware it should work.