# multiple watch-only wallet management: suggestions?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, watch-only-wallet

I have a bunch of wallets for which I expect to cold-sign transactions when required. I have set these up as watch-only hot wallets using `monero-wallet-cli` `--generate-from-view-key`, but would prefer not to have multiple wallet daemons running at the same time: after all, my node daemon (`monerod` and its `data.mdb`) is the real aggregator and data store!
 Any suggestions on how I can manage multiple wallets(hot or cold) please? How are businesses / DNMs currently managing these(multiple wallets per customer) ?

Answer (score 2):

One daemon instance is enough. It can service multiple wallets simultaneously. The data stored by the daemon in the .mdb is all public knowledge (the blockchain), anyway.

Wallet-specific data is stored in the cache file. See [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/what-data-do-the-wallet-files-contain) for more details. So really, you can keep the daemon running and have few instances of the wallet running and talking to the same daemon. Each wallet stores only some data relevant to it, while the daemon stores the entire public ledger (blockchain).

Comment: hmm, that is actually what I was trying to avoid: so basically merchants/DNMs/organisations are currently running multiple wallets(wallet rpc daemons, not node daemons as only one node rpc is required) simultaneously huh: sounds a bit resource intensive(could have been more efficient if handled by, say, a single wallet rpc daemon) ... okay thanks though.

Comment: I'm not sure about RPC actually. Maybe someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: I mean it is doable, in python I'd open multiple `Popen PIPE`s, but was hoping just the one `monero-wallet-cli` rpc could be pinged by a solution that updates the required wallet file accordingly, coz after all the (wallet)rpc is able to accept multiple calls: so restricting `monero-wallet-cli` to one wallet only sounds a bit, well, 'restrictive' :p

Comment: Ah, I see. But if you need to track payments you'd use the same address, and issue different payment ID to customers. You don't need x wallets, you need 1 wallet and x payment IDs.

Comment: http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/what-is-an-integrated-address

Comment: hmm, _'Not many exchanges and other merchants currently support integrated addresses'_ ... I still think merchants/DNMs/organisations are running a different/more segregated solution

Comment: It's either that or plain text payment ID. As far as I know Poloniex uses the same address for all incoming payments but they give a different payment ID for each user.