# I want to view addresses that I've sent payments to in the past?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

This was working in the past, but I recently did `rescan_bc` and now when I do `show_transfers` I can only see amounts and tx_id.

I assume this is related to: [When sending monero to an address. Does my wallet keep track of the history of where it was sent to?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6539/when-sending-monero-to-an-address-does-my-wallet-keep-track-of-the-history-of-w)

So it seems that `rescan_bc` clears the wallet history?

I often view sent-to addresses to confirm I am sending to a correct address again (to avoid phishing/address swaps). I assume using `address_book` would be a better option here.

Slowly I am getting the hang of the Monero cli, I am just looking for confirmation on the above. thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of historical destination addresses is not something that can be obtained from the blockchain, so the only place it is is in your wallet cache. If you clear it, then this info is lost forever. Whether you remove the cache file or restore from seed or run a rescan_bc, it's gone.